# Not displaying video immediately when using WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I was wondering what is the best way to not display video right after calling `getUserMedia();` with WebRTC. Many tutorials seem to have you display video immediately, but for real use-cases, it often makes sense to not display video until the user presses a button.

I am not sure how most apps handle this, but currently, I am thinking that perhaps it is possible to accomplish this with styling by not displaying the video element on the page until the user presses a button, but that would mean that the stream would technically be "on", just not displayed on the page. So, I was wondering if there was a way using JS to maybe set or access the stream later when pressing a button.

It seems like when using `getUserMedia();` that the stream has to be set and stored immediately ([below is code from the Google Code Lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#3)) so I am not sure if this is not possible.

```js
// Local stream that will be reproduced on the video.
let localStream;

// Handles success by adding the MediaStream to the video element.
function gotLocalMediaStream(mediaStream) {
  localStream = mediaStream;
  localVideo.srcObject = mediaStream;
}

// Initializes media stream.
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaStreamConstraints)
  .then(gotLocalMediaStream).catch(handleLocalMediaStreamError);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply don't display it.

You can keep that stream in your variable.  Just don't assign it as the `srcObject` on a video element.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Do you know if doing it this way is a best practice? I am not sure how most WebRTC apps handle this.

Comment: @mso4491 In general, I think it's a good practice to actually show the stream if you've requested it from the user.  Not only does this visibly show to the user that the stream is actually working, but it also provides a visual reason for their webcam being on.  Many cameras have an LED that shows activity.  People get creeped out if their camera is on but doesn't appear to actually be in-use.  Of course if your application has a specific reason for this and it's clear to the user, it's fine.  And, there's definitely nothing technical wrong with not displaying it.

Comment: I have had good success with this technique. “Best practice?” I don’t know. But “good practice?” Yes.

Comment: @Brad That makes sense. I was thinking in case the user is not ready to show their webcam right when they enter the app. Not sure if you have used whereby.com (used to be appearin) but they are one example of an app where the user starts with their camera off even though the app seems to be a `getUserMedia` request upon the user joing a meeting. Hangouts does a good job handling this behavior by asking the user to make this decision before joining, but I am not sure how complicated it would be to implement something like that.